# Cgroup instance not creating “net_cls.classid” file

Tags: linux, redhat-enterprise-linux

After creating cgroup i can see it is listed under 'lscgroup'

`cgcreate -g net_cls:123456`

```
#lscgroup | grep 123456

net_cls,net_prio:/123456
```

But no child files got created under `/sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls/`

I assume this must be automatically created as soon as cgroup is created. Specifically i am looking for `net_cls.classid` file.

Any pointers about this ?